# Strange and unexpected behavior of the constructor of an enum in Dart

Tags: dart, enums, constructor

I’m writing a code with a `enum`.

You can run the code [here in a DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a97eb1f9e61c3a86fd9ed0bc9f596faf).

The `enum` constructor has a optional named parameter `codeAndDescription`. An enumeration value does not specify the value of parameter `codeAndDescription` (which by default should be an empty string). If I print this value, it does not print an empty string, but `'null'`. Does anyone know if this is a bug or if I’m wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I agree, it's definitely a bug. At the bottom of the window in DartPad, you can click on the button that says "stable channel" and switch it to "beta channel" which uses a newer version of dart. The bug seems to be fixed in the beta version.

Comment: Thank you @mmcdon20! In the meantime, I will switch to the beta channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a know bug, as mmcdon20 also mention, which have been fixed for the upcoming Dart 2.18 version. This version is right now in beta.

You can find the bug report here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49216